# Collaborative Editing GPKGs with QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, geopackage

Is there a way to have two users editing the same GPKG file (on different locations in the coordinates) collaboratively in a remote setting?

We can also use something like a Virtual Desktop with multi-session but I'd like to know if it is possible with QGIS.